# Bootstrap: How to show modal without animation just for first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my current project i have a link that opens modal with login form inside. When user enters wrong credentials then I reload page and show again login modal with errors. Currently I am using following code to show modal on page load:

```
$(function() {
    $('#login-modal').modal('show')
});
```

Everything is OK, but I want disable modal animation just for first time. How can I do this?

There is nothing in documentation about disabling animation just for first time

Comment: Please read docs before asking questions

Comment: There is nothing in documentation about disabling animation just for first time

Comment: Nothing in question about only disabling only first time either

Comment: So toggle the fade class as needed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-remove-animation):

> For modals that simply appear rather than fade in to view, remove the `.fade` class from your modal markup.

Comment: I want to disable animation just for first time, not entirely

Comment: Then when triggering the modal, also add `.fade` class on it on some delay, [something like this](http://www.bootply.com/vXlFiLWR6X).

Answer (score -1):

you should hard code the milliseconds inside modal function for quick response.

Comment: Welcome to tackOverflow. When answering, it's very appreciated to provide examples rather than just textual explanation.